# ViewにTapGestureを実装すると、UITabBarが反応しなくなる

Tags: swift

SwiftとXcodeで、ViewとUITabBarだけがあるシンプルなシーンを作りました。
以下のようなコードを書くと、TabBarをタップしても反応しなくなります。

タップジェスチャーを実装する前は問題なくTabBarがタップに反応していたので、タップジェスチャーを実装したことが問題なのだと思います。
UITabBarのisUserInteractionEnabledをtrueにしてもfalseにしても影響はありませんでした。

どうしたら、UITabBarを問題なく動作させることができますか？

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITabBarDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tabBar: UITabBar!
    
    @objc func tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        if sender.state == .ended {
            print("タップ")
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tabBar.delegate = self
        

        let tapGesture:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
                       target: self,
                       action: #selector(ViewController.tapped(_:)))
        tapGesture.delegate = self
        
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        //tabBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true//false
    }
    
    // タブバーのボタンを押した時
    func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
      // item.tag の数値を見て押下されたボタンを判別する
      switch item.tag {
        case 1:
            print("1")
            break
          // UITabBarItem 1 がタップされた
        case 2:
            print("2")
            break
          // UITabBarItem 2 がタップされた
        default:
          print("どのボタンでもない")
      }
    }

    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: ちょっと検索して見ただけで[こんな記事](https://qiita.com/RS_Dessin/items/f1d337289589b4c5f551)が見つかりました。参考にしてみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。望み通りの挙動になりました。

Comment: 是非とも望み通りに動かすことのできた内容を自己回答として投稿してみてください。(今すぐはできないかもしれませんが、その「承認」もお願いします。)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[以下のコード](https://qiita.com/RS_Dessin/items/f1d337289589b4c5f551)のように、tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = falseを追加してあげればできました。

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tabBar.delegate = self
    

    let tapGesture:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
                   target: self,
                   action: #selector(ViewController.tapped(_:)))
    tapGesture.delegate = self
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```